# How to use selenium in python to auto login when there is a popup authenticate window

Tags: python, selenium

This is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('url')

wait(driver, 30).until(EC.alert_is_present())

alert=driver.switch_to_alert()


alert.send_keys('user')
alert.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
alert.send_keys('pass')
alert.accept()
```

The popup window is launched, but nothing changes after it. Any ideas?

Comment: So the popup window appears without you having to click on anything?

Comment: I thought alert windows were special windows that only take OK or Cancel as input.  If you can enter a username and password, is it really an _alert_ window, or just a generic pop-up window?

Comment: it is a pop up window. it ask for username and password.

Comment: OK, so it's not really an _alert_ window.  So, I don't think `switch_to_alert` will work.

Comment: Any suggestions? What should I do?

Comment: You can use one of the `find_element_by_X` functions to locate the input fields and then send input to them.  If they have IDs, then `find_element_by_id` is the best function to use.  Otherwise you could use `find_element_by_name`, etc.

Comment: Does it really web pop up or `Windows` native window?

Comment: username = selenium.find_element_by_id("User Name")
   password = selenium.find_element_by_id("Password")

   username.send_keys("YourUsername")
   password.send_keys("Pa55worD")

   selenium.find_element_by_name("Log In").click()                                  Still not working

Comment: When you click on the login button, then it leads you to a window with the popup and ask for user name and password @Andersson

Comment: @WillWill, can you click right button to see `http` source code on user/password input field?

Comment: @Andersson it doesn't allow you to see it. the website is portal.adp.com

Comment: @WillWill, if so, you will not be able to complete authentication with `Selenium` as it allow to operate only with web elements

Comment: @Andersson is there a way that I can do it?

Comment: Websites can't prevent you from looking at the page source.  On Firefox, if you right-click anywhere on the page, you will get a menu with "View Page Source" as an option.  I imagine other browsers work in similar ways.  Once you see the source, you can find the `id` value of the input fields.  ("Log In" probably is not the id value.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to authenticate with following `url` form:

```
driver.get('https://username:password@portal.adp.com')
```

Change `username` and `password` to your real credentials.

Comment: This actually works..I just need to find the correct URL.

Comment: @UlfGjerdingen, "won't work anymore" or "it doesn't work in your case"? This was the solution for this particular case- I didn't claim that this should **"work in chrome"**. Your web-app might use different authentication scheme, so this approach is not acceptable **in your particular** case. There is no reason for downvote, so please  cancel it

Comment: true. sorry. i need to edit it first, then i'll remove my downvote.

Comment: how about if the password contains the @ sign